# Can we call a single ajax functionality at multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

How can I fire a single ajax function at multiple Id's, like I want to upload a image file, and I use ajax call for this,

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var uploaded_files_location = "<?=$http1?>img/photos_image";

                var ccal= document.getElementById("clickfinder").value;

                new AjaxUpload($('#vpb_upload_button'),
                           $('#vpb_upload_button1'),
                           $('#vpb_upload_button2'),
                           $('#vpb_upload_button3'),
                           $('#vpb_upload_button4'),
               {action: 'any.php',
                name: 'file_to_upload',
                onSubmit: function(file, file_extensions)
                { // code }
               });
```

and I am calling this like this

```
    <pre>
       <div id="#vpb_upload_button" onclick="idseter('id');"></div>    
     </pre>
```

Can anyone assist me how can I do this and how can I call onclick function as I want to call some id seter at this event.

Comment: An `id` should be unique. It was meant to be unique, so what you are asking for is not logical. Can't you use `class` instead of `id` ?

Comment: Yes, I use class too, but actually I need to call this onclick function too, and has to specify the effect of uploaded image at diffrent places, so for this purpose i put id setter to return the id of parent of clicked element to a hidden field, and act accordingly, thanks for commenting

Comment: The problem is that since `id` was designed to be unique, even if you jQuery selector is aiming multiple DOM elements. Only one would be catch. So if you want to collect multiple DOM elements at once, you should use `class` instead of `id` ;)

Comment: @Masadow you actually can find multiple elements with same ID using `"[id=xxx]"` selector....  I'm not suggesting is good idea....just pointing out it can be done

Comment: Guys, I also have used class for this purpose,              
        new AjaxUpload($('.uploader'),
                {
                    action: 'abc.php',
                    name: 'file_to_upload',
                    onSubmit: function(file, file_extensions)
                    { /*code here */ }});
           but its pointing only first element, other are not working

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, but it's very ugly since id was not designed in a such way.

Comment: @Masadow agree...unfortunately sometimes with legacy code you run into it

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your selector is wrong.

You should use `$('##vpb_upload_button')`.

However, I would suggest you to use classes instead of id since id are meant to be unique.

What you can do is

```
new AjaxUpload($('.vpb_upload_button')) {
    //code
}
```

And then in your html

```
<div class="vpb_upload_button" onclick="idseter('id');">1</div>
<div class="vpb_upload_button" onclick="idseter('id');">2</div>
<div class="vpb_upload_button" onclick="idseter('id');">3</div>
```

EDIT

You can do the following to make a multiple call to AjaxUpload

```
$('.upload').each(function() {
    new AjaxUpload($(this)) {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, I do the same and its not working, can u check at this link [click here](http://www.iposterpix.com/update/step7_update.php), plus icon

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? Can you show a bit more of your code ? Can you show `idseter` function. What do you expect from AjaxUpload ? When do you expect it to be called ?

Comment: As when u will visit that link above, you can see diffrent sections of "+" icon, I need to make upload the image in those sections at click event of that icon as i have updated my code above, for make a collage maker. now i think u may understand this.

Comment: Guys, I also have used class for this purpose,              
        new AjaxUpload($('.uploader'),
                {
                    action: 'abc.php',
                    name: 'file_to_upload',
                    onSubmit: function(file, file_extensions)
                    { /*code here */ }});
           but its pointing only first element, other are not working

Comment: yes, its works by using class, please give me some alternate also for onclick function, can we get the id of particular element so we can judge the resultant id.

Comment: `$(".upload").click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); }` ?